# Parsing a String into a HashSet

Tags: java

Currently my application keeps getting hung up on a method that I have created which parses a String (Not String[]) to a Set.

**How can I optimize the parseTopicString() method?**

This method takes a HashSet and converts its values into a long String, for example {string1}{string2}{string3}... and so forth depending on how many items are in the Set at any given time.

```
    private String genTopicString(Set<String> topicSet) {
    StringBuilder res = new StringBuilder();
    for (String str : topicSet) {
      res.append("{").append(str).append("}");
    }
    return res.toString();
  }
```

This method I believe has the issue, it converts that String back to a Set.

```
  private Set<String> parseTopicString(String str) {
    Set<String> res = new HashSet<String>();
    String currentStr = str;
    while (currentStr.split("\\{").length >= 2) {
      String[] parts = currentStr.split("\\{");
      if (parts[0].split("\\}").length >= 2) {
        res.add(parts[0].split("\\}")[0]);
        currentStr = parts[0].split("\\}")[1];
      }
    }
    return res;
  }
```

This is where the application gets hung up

```
if (!(prefs.getString(CURRENT_TOPICS, "").isEmpty())) {
  currentTopics = parseTopicString(prefs.getString(CURRENT_TOPICS, ""));
  saveServiceTopics();
}
```

Comment: step through in a debugger and watch what happens to `currentStr`.

Comment: [1] In case an exception is killing the thread, wrap all the code in a try/catch(Throwable) and print the exception to somewhere you would see it. [2] isolate the problematic input data and run that data through while stepping through with a debugger [3] If the program is truly hung (deadlock/livelock or infinite loop), then get a stack trace thread dump and identify exactly what method and line of code it is locked in.

Comment: What is `prefs`? Is it an android `SharedPreferences` object? If so, why can't you use `putStringSet`?

Comment: Calling `split` so many times is probably a large factor in the slowness. (You end up creating O(N^2) strings and discarding them)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the most efficient, but at least it's easier to understand:

```
Set<String> result = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(
    string.substring(1, string.length() - 1).split("\\}\\{")));
```